# Can I use only Karate DSL extension for VS Code to access database and kafka?

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

At work, there was a need to automate some of the regression tests.
The only tools available are Visual Studio for working with C#, which I know a bit, and VS Code, which is used for sending messages to kafka.

The easiest way to get started was to use the Karate plugin for VS Code, which has already helped me automate a few tests while I was learning in the process.

The problem is that most tests in one way or another require either changing the data in the MS SQL DB or validating the data in it.

I've seen that Karate can work with databases if you add a DBUtils class, those examples are in the documentation, but in videos and articles about it people are working in IDEs like IDEA, and I can't put it on my work computer yet.

Question: can I just add the class from the example in the documentation and continue working in VS Code? Will this work?
What is the "right" way to do it in my case?

For example, I was able to put karate-config.js with settings in the root of the project and it worked.

Thanks.

Examples I've looked at:
[dogs.feature](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature)
[DBUtils](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/demo/util/DbUtils.java)

Comment: hope someone else can help with a more detailed answer, but `DBUtils` will require you to compile Java. some tips can be found here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/karate-netty#custom-classpath - but I agree, currently this is biased towards Java teams that can use Maven or Gradle

Comment: @PeterThomas Thanks, I suspected something like that.
But I still hope that it will be enough to add classes to work with MS SQL and kafka, put maven and change Run Mode of Extension to maven.